# Swift - Use common variable for multiple datatypes

Tags: ios, swift

I have many optional variables which are subclasses of the same class:

```
var variable1: Experience.subclass1!
var variable2: Experience.subclass2!
var variable3: Experience.subclass3!
...
```

I want to use a common variable which can copy the value from any of these optional variables for easy code writing. Example:

```
var commonVariable = variable1
...
commonVariable = variable2 // change the value inside another function
```

Any ideas on how to enable this functionality? This will greatly simplify my code.

Comment: Use a protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make Subclass1, Subclass2 and Subclass3 all conform to some protocol.

Your protocol might take the form:

```
protocol Experienced {

     var somethingCommonYouNeed: String { get set }

     func someCommonFunction() -> String
}
```

Then you would make 'Subclass1' 'Subclass2' and 'Subclass3' all conform to the `Experienced` protocol.

```
class Subclass1: Experienced {

   var somethingCommonYouNeed = "Hello"

   func someCommonFunction() -> String {

        return "Hello"
   }

   ...existing code...
}
```

Then you would make the type of commonVariable `Experienced`.

```
var commonVariable: Experienced!
```

From there, you can say `commonVariable.somethingCommonYouNeed` to access your property or a function that is shared across all instances that conform the to 'Experienced' protocol.

Answer (score 1):

If `commonVariable` is only for common functionality then you can use

```
var commonVariable: Experience = variable1
...
commonVariable = variable2
```

then you will use any value of `commonVariable` as `Experience`.

Comment: I am getting the following error `Cannot convert value of type 'Experience.subclass1' to specified type 'Experience'`